# How do you use the action and extra properties on an AntDesign List in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im trying to use the extra and actions features on the Ant Design List in my react app.

I've tried both of these steps inside and outside the List.Item.Meta, although the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/list/) describes these as properties available on List.Item.

```
<List
            itemLayout="horizontal"
            dataSource={users}
            // renderItem={users.map(user => (
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item key={item.uid}>
                <List.Item.Meta
                  title={item.name}
                  description={item.organisation}
                />
                  extra={item.email}
                  actions={<Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: `${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`,
                      state: { item },
                    }}
                  >
                    More
                  </Link>
                  }

                  {/* 
                    actions={<Icon
                    type="close-circle"
                    theme="filled"
                    onClick={`${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`}
                  />}
                */}

              </List.Item>
            // )
          )}
          />
```

Outside List.Item.Meta, they just print as text. Inside,they are ignored.

This [tutorial](http://blog.agileactors.com/blog/2018/3/28/using-react-firebase-and-ant-design-to-quickly-prototype-web-applications) shows how its used without the Meta.

How do I use the extra and action properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extra` and `actions` like you said are properties on the `List.Item` itself, so you would provide it as props to it:

```
<List.Item key={item.uid}
  extra={item.email}
  actions={<Link to={{
     pathname: `${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`,
     state: { item },
   }}
  >
    More
  </Link>}
>
   <List.Item.Meta
       title={item.name}
       description={item.organisation}
   />
</List.Item>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rqmrce?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Agney. I saw the Ant D documentation that I also linked to the question. I tried your suggestion. It does not work. It prints the email address with right alignment (I don't know why) and skips the link altogether

Comment: It's hard to comment on this without seeing the code, can you create a reproduction? The stackblitz I have linked to is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You cant use action and extra properties for List.item.meta,
they are only supported for List.item

At the end of antd documention for every component, you can check what properties does the item support.

Ex:-
[image]

To use in List item, make sure those properties are given dis way, You are rendering them as text inside tags instead of using them as properties

```
<List
            itemLayout="horizontal"
            dataSource={users}
            // renderItem={users.map(user => (
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item 
                 key={item.uid}
                  extra={item.email}
                  actions={<Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: `${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`,
                      state: { item },
                    }}
                  >
                    More
                  </Link>
                  }                
                  >
                <List.Item.Meta
                  title={item.name}
                  description={item.organisation}
                />


                  {/* 
                    actions={<Icon
                    type="close-circle"
                    theme="filled"
                    onClick={`${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`}
                  />}
                */}

              </List.Item>
            // )
          )}
          />
```

Comment: Thank you. I read the documents - what they don't explain is how to use the properties. I know these are properties on List rather than Meta but some examples in SO have them inside Meta - so that's why I tried it there too. I can't see the difference between the way I rendered the extra and the way you have - we're both using extra={item.email}. I managed to get this working. Thanks again for trying to help.